# How could i use the indesign's XML (content data) into a flex application that reproduce the same layout as indesign?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flex4, ria

Basically, i've created xml tags into indesign and i tags all the document. then i export it as a xml file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <descriptionbloc>
        <title>title of the book</title>
        <subtitle> subtitle of the book </subtitle>
        <author> the author </author>
        <description>  bla bla bla </description>
        <reference> 16 x 24 cm – 224 pages – 2011
                    <isbn>9780 440 4 04</isbn>
            <price>18</price>
        </reference>
        <image href="file://Links/DD1004.eps"></image>
    </descriptionbloc>

<description>
...etc
</description>
</root>
```

there are huge information.

My idea is to create a component that reproduce the 4 bloc per page that represent the data (it's a catalogue)
and populate with the xml.

I'll post some code later, I would like some ideas that I did not think or example of use.
i have work with some rss viewver but i'm stuck.

thanks all.

Comment: Is `<description>...etc</description>` suppose to be `<descriptionbloc>...etc</descriptionbloc>`?

Comment: It's rather difficult to figure out what you're asking here.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do in InDesign. Check out the book A Designer's Guide to Adobe InDesign and XML for specific detailed directions.

You can import the XML data directly into InDesign and flow it from page to page and map Paragraph and Character styles to your XML tags.

If you want to clone a specific set of placeholders and how they are formatted, InDesign also allows you to clone the placeholders and their formatting when importing an XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I can definitively recommend Jim's book : A Designer's Guide to Adobe InDesign and XML. I owe it (him) almost all my XML knowledge ;) The repeating process you are looking at is widely detailed.